# Heartbeat external plugin configuration format

Tags: linux, high-availability, heartbeat

I have developed an external Heartbeat v1 plugin, which expects its configuration by means of environment variables.

AFAIK, this is what Heartbeat provides when configuring the plugin using the following entry in `/etc/heartbeat/ha.cf`:

```
stonith external/my_plugin /etc/ha.d/my_plugin-hostname.conf
```

What I am not quite certain about is the format that `/etc/ha.d/my_plugin-<hostname>.conf` is supposed to have (as documentation seem to be somewhat non-existent). Right now, I used the following attempt:

```
<hostname> target <hostname>
<hostname> auth_token <some_token>
<hostname> proxy_uri <some_url>
```

Unfortunately, `my_plugin` is called with the following parameters:

```
target: <hostname>
auth_token: proxy_uri
proxy_uri <some_url>
```

So, the `auth_token` parameter is messed up and I frankly have no clue why... I am dumping the environment using `export` at the beginning of the script, so I am quite certain that this is what heartbeat supplies the script with.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: The config file format is actually a space-delimited list of the configuration parameters in the order returned by the `getconfignames` operation (`target auth_token proxy_uri` in my case), so the file correctly looks like this:

```
<hostname> <some_token> <some_url>
```